# time and work question how to solve this

Tags: contest-math

A,B,C are employed to do a piece of work for Rs 5290. A and B together are supposed to do 19/23 th  of the work and B and C together 8/23 th of the work then A should be paid

A.Rs 4250

B.Rs 3450

C.Rs 1950

D.Rs 2290

sir can you tell me how to solve this

Comment: You should edit your question, it is hard to understand.

Comment: $15/23\cdot 5290=3450$; so, B

Comment: B and C together will do 8/23 of the work, so what part of the work will A do? Then the corresponding part of the whole payment shall be...?

Comment: ans is right 3450. but can you explain that 15/23 how it come-- Michael Galuza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you reproduced the question *exactly* ? As it stands, it makes little sense.

However, *interpreting* that in a *certain* time, A and B working together can do 19/23 of the work, while B and C (in the same time) can do 8/23 of the work, we can write two equations

**A + B = 19/23**

**B + C = 8/23**

Adding the two, **A + 2B + C = 27/23**

*Assuming* that A,B and C together would just complete the work in the given time, B can complete only **27/23 - 23/23 = 4/23** of the work, and A can complete **19/23 - 4/23 = 15/23** of the work.

Thus A's pay should be **$\frac{15}{23}\cdot 5290 =3450 $**

Answer (score 1):

We're going to write $A,B,C$ for the fraction of the total work that each person does. We are given that
$$A+B=\frac{19}{23}$$
$$B+C=\frac{8}{23}$$
And we finally impose 
$$A+B+C=1$$
as they must sum to 1.
Really we only need the last 2 equations. We substitute the second into the 3rd to give $A+\frac{8}{23}=1$, i.e.
$A=1-\frac{8}{23}=\frac{15}{23}$. So $A$ should be paid $\frac{15}{23}*5290=3450$

Comment: great. i am asked this qustion many frends of mine no body solve and explian but this explanation is great.